# Function that returns a multiplication table fails with negative numbers

Tags: javascript

Hello I was having issue with this function. I wanted to create a function that takes a number, a starting point and a final point, and writes the multiplication table of the number from the starting point to the ending point. For example, tabmul(10,2,4) returns

10.2 = 20

10.3 = 30

10.4 = 40

This is all good but it doesn't work for negative numbers. For example, 
tabmul(10,-4,-1) should generate

10.-4 = -40

10.-3 = -30

10.-2 = -20

10.-1 = -10

but it doesn't return anything. This is my code:

```
function tabmul(a,b,c){ \\function that generates the multiplication table
    var myarray = new Array();
    var x
    for(x=b; x<=c; x++){
        myarray[x - b] = a*x;
        document.write(a + "." + x + "=" + myarray[x - b] + "<br>")
    }
}
var a = prompt("Enter the number whose table you want to calculate: ","");
var b = prompt("Enter the place where you want the table to start","");
var c = prompt("Enter the place where you want the table to end","");
\\ this checks if the starting point is smaller or equal than the ending point of the table
if (0 <= c-b) {
  tabmul(a,b,c);

} else {
    alert("The starting point is bigger than the ending point");
}
```

Comment: you're checking if the starting point is bigger than the end point, and -1 (end point) is bigger than -4 (starting point)

Comment: It would also be better to replace "." with " x ". ;-)

Comment: Is that so? I think 0 <= c-b is the same as b <= c, starting point is less or equal than ending point.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger and stepping through the code to see where it is not behaving the way you expect?

Comment: how do I download a debugger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are comparing strings. This is because **prompt returns strings**. you need to convert `a,b,c` to numbers. Also you are using wrong symbols for comments, you need to correct those.

```js
function tabmul(a,b,c){ //function that generates the multiplication table
    a = Number(a);
    b = Number(b);
    c = Number(c);
    var myarray = new Array();
    var x
    for(x=b;x<=c;x++){
        myarray[x-b] = a*x;
        document.write(a+"."+x+"="+myarray[x-b]+"<br/>")
    }
}
var a = prompt("Enter the number whose table you want to calculate: ","");
var b = prompt("Enter the place where you want the table to start","");
var c = prompt("Enter the place where you want the table to end","");
if(0 <= c-b){ //this checks if the starting point is smaller or equal than the ending point of the table
tabmul(a,b,c);
}
else{
    alert("The starting point is bigger than the ending point");
}
```

Comment: Thanks. When you input numeric parameters into a function f(x) you created, it always assumes they are strings instead of numbers? Thank you.

Comment: prompt returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

You should also convert your input to a number using `Number` or `parseInt` to make sure it is numeric.

After that you can run into problems referring to an array by index using a negative number.

```
myarray[x-b] // can fail if x-b<0. Also for a large number n it will insert empty elements in your array up to N.
```

For example take the following:

```
var myarray= new Array();
myarray[-4]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myarray));
// result "[]"
myarray= new Array();
myarray[10]=1;
console.log(JSON.stringify(myarray));
// result "[null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,1]"
```

You could convert it to a string:

```
myarray['"' + (x-b) + '"'] = a*x;
```

Or you could just use push() and your indexes will start with zero.:

```
 for(x=b;x<=c;x++){
    myarray.push(a*x);
    document.write(a+"."+x+"="+myarray(myarray.length-1)+"<br/>")
}
```

Comment: push seems an interesting function. I am new to programming so I'm still learning, sorry for my questions. I will learn more about the push and .length functions

Answer (score 0):

1)Make normal names for function arguments.
2)Use indentation and 'let' in 'for' loop instead of 'var' right before:

```
for(let x = b; x <= c; x++){}
```

3)Don't forget semicolons.

```
function multiplication(val, start, end) {
  if(end - start <= 0) return;
  for(let i = start; i <= end; i++) {
    console.log(val + ' * ' + i + ' = ' + val * i);
  }
}
multiplication(10, -4, -1);

10 * -4 = -40
10 * -3 = -30
10 * -2 = -20
10 * -1 = -10
```

Comment: I come from a math background and I'm used to using the whole alphabet and greek letters for variables and functions, it is hard to see a function having variable "start" instead of "x", but I guess I will have to get used to. I think the answer is about converting the input to numbers.

Comment: It's just that you should write code that others would be able to read :)